# Preventing nested grouping when adding rows to pivot table in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

[image]

With the picture above in mind, I am trying to form pivots for each different age category and gender, using `Excel 2016`.
Currently, however, when I add age and gender to the `row` category of `pivot tables`, it forms a nested group by.

Instead, I need to have un-nested/distinct pivots for the genders and age categories.

Is there anyway to achieve this in Excel?

Comment: That's how pivot tables work. Row fields are always grouped within any other row fields to the left of them. It sounds like you need separate pivot tables.

Comment: Indeed, separate. But that calls for a lot of manual work, and I was hoping there is some way to automatically achieve it

Comment: Copy/paste the pivot and swap the row field.

Comment: I am *slightly* uneasy with that
Just hoping somebody has a different solution. If not, then I will have to accept your suggestion (and lose hope ;) )

Comment: You can program it. What you can't do is make a pivot table not group its fields; it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Rory what you say makes sense. Feel free to add your comment as an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write code to create multiple copies of your pivot table, or just copy and paste manually, but you can't make a pivot table not group nested fields. That's the entire point of a pivot table, after all.

Answer (score 2):

This one might be helpful Check it out:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-pivottable-default-layout-options-efd8569c-f07a-43c1-9db2-4f2912a0f94e

You need to change both of these settings:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Unfortunately the linked article only talks about changing the layout, whereas I want to change the calculations too (hence I don't need a nested group of gender within age to form).

Comment: Unfortunately it still did not address my need. As @Rory put it, I really need separate pivot tables, but without the hassle of making them manually (I have a lot of rows to group by)

Answer (score 0):

Within Pivot table
Click on Design (after “Pivot Table Analyze” menu group)
Click on Report Layout
Click on Show in Tabular Form